# jQuery - how to move figure in coordinationsystem

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard, game-physics

Lets say that I have this code:

```
<div id="gameFrame">
   <div id="figure"></div>
</div>
```

Where the figure div is lets say a picture of a figure. How can i use jQuery in order to move the figure inside the gameFrame with the keyboard keys up down left and right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the exception of keyboard use, what you are trying to do has already been done in the jQuery Draggable module: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#default. You might be able to use what they have done their as a start point. The actual code is here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js.

The downside is that you might have to put considerable effort into extending/modifying the code, and it will still likely depend on other jQuery code.

Then again, you could probably whip something up in a fraction of the size of the jQuery code. But, I thought I'd post this in case no one else turned anything up.

If you want to do it yourself, the general process would be:

1. Wrap the item you want to move in a container (like another `div`) and set the position to be relative using CSS.
2. Bind keyboard events for the arrow keys
3. When a key is pressed, modify the positioning of the element to move it (CSS attributes like `left` and `top`)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my [demo](http://jsbin.com/ofudi4/3/edit):

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    // Left
    if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
      $("#moveMe").animate({marginLeft: "-=100px"}, {queue:false});
       return false;
    }
    // Top
    if (e.keyCode == 38) { 
      $("#moveMe").animate({marginTop: "-=100px"}, {queue:false});
       return false;
    }
    // Right
    if (e.keyCode == 39) { 
      $("#moveMe").animate({marginLeft: "+=100px"}, {queue:false});
       return false;
    }
    // Bottom
    if (e.keyCode == 40) { 
      $("#moveMe").animate({marginTop: "+=100px"}, {queue:false});
       return false;
    }
});
```

​
In your case you would need to check for boundaries after each move, so the figure doesn't move outside the frame.